# Gparted bug? Window closes but it is not exiting

Tags: debian, gparted

Gparted is still running after the window is closed.

This can broke shell script, because you can only close it by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Note that the window closes ok when I click on (X close), and the partition table are saved - the only trouble is that it is still hanging the terminal.

Debian 8X - running `gparted` with `sudo` (or with `su` that doesn't make any difference).

This is what appears on terminal when GParted window is already closed (but GParted process still running):

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknow error -1
Too few arguments.
======================
libparted : 3.2
======================
```